# Convert multiple dataframes into a multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bunch of stock data downloaded from yahoo finance. Each dataframe looks like this:

```
          Date  Open  High   Low  Close  Adj Close  Volume
0   2019-03-11  2.73  2.81  2.71   2.75       2.75  243900
1   2019-03-12  2.66  2.78  2.66   2.75       2.75   69200
2   2019-03-13  2.75  2.80  2.71   2.77       2.77   61200
3   2019-03-14  2.77  2.79  2.75   2.75       2.75   48800
4   2019-03-15  2.76  2.79  2.75   2.79       2.79  124400
..         ...   ...   ...   ...    ...        ...     ...
282 2020-04-22  3.61  3.75  3.61   3.71       3.71  312900
283 2020-04-23  3.74  3.77  3.66   3.76       3.76   99800
284 2020-04-24  3.78  3.78  3.63   3.63       3.63   89100
285 2020-04-27  3.70  3.70  3.55   3.64       3.64   60600
286 2020-04-28  3.70  3.74  3.64   3.70       3.70  248300
```

I need to concat the data so it looks like the below multi-index format and I'm at a loss. I've tried a number of `pd.concat([list of dfs], zip(cols,symbols), axis=[0,1])` combos with no luck so any help is appreciated!

```
                Adj Close         Close             High              Low               Open               Volume               
                CHNR  GNSS  SGRP  CHNR  GNSS  SGRP  CHNR  GNSS  SGRP  CHNR  GNSS  SGRP  CHNR  GNSS  SGRP   CHNR    GNSS   SGRP
Date                                                                                                                          
2019-04-30      1.85  3.08  0.69  1.85  3.08  0.69  1.94  3.10  0.70  1.74  3.05  0.67  1.74  3.07  0.70  24800   23900  30400
2019-05-01      1.81  3.15  0.65  1.81  3.15  0.65  1.85  3.17  0.69  1.75  3.06  0.62  1.76  3.09  0.67  15500   72800  85900
2019-05-02      1.80  3.12  0.66  1.80  3.12  0.66  1.87  3.16  0.66  1.76  3.10  0.65  1.80  3.16  0.65  12900   28100  97200
2019-05-03      1.85  3.14  0.67  1.85  3.14  0.67  1.89  3.19  0.69  1.74  3.06  0.62  1.74  3.12  0.62  43200   31300  27500
2019-05-06      1.85  3.13  0.66  1.85  3.13  0.66  1.89  3.25  0.69  1.75  3.11  0.65  1.79  3.11  0.67  37000   50200  31500
...              ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...    ...     ...    ...
2020-04-22      0.93  3.71  0.73  0.93  3.71  0.73  1.04  3.75  0.73  0.93  3.61  0.69  0.93  3.61  0.72   2600  312900  14600
2020-04-23      1.01  3.76  0.74  1.01  3.76  0.74  1.01  3.77  0.77  0.94  3.66  0.73  0.94  3.74  0.73   2500   99800  15200
2020-04-24      1.05  3.63  0.76  1.05  3.63  0.76  1.05  3.78  0.77  0.92  3.63  0.74  1.05  3.78  0.74   4400   89100   1300
2020-04-27      1.03  3.64  0.76  1.03  3.64  0.76  1.07  3.70  0.77  0.92  3.55  0.76  1.07  3.70  0.77   6200   60600   3500
2020-04-28      1.00  3.70  0.77  1.00  3.70  0.77  1.07  3.74  0.77  0.96  3.64  0.75  1.07  3.70  0.77  22300  248300  26100
```

EDIT per Quang Hoang's suggestion:

Tried:

```
ret =  pd.concat(stock_data.values(), keys=stocks, axis=1)
ret = ret.swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
```

Got the following output which looks much closer but still off a bit:

```
           Date   Open   High    Low  Close Adj Close Volume       Date  Open  High   Low Close Adj Close    Volume       Date  Open  High   Low Close Adj Close Volume
           CHNR   CHNR   CHNR   CHNR   CHNR      CHNR   CHNR       GNSS  GNSS  GNSS  GNSS  GNSS      GNSS      GNSS       SGRP  SGRP  SGRP  SGRP  SGRP      SGRP   SGRP
0    2010-04-29  11.39  11.74  11.39  11.57     11.57   3100 2019-03-11  2.73  2.81  2.71  2.75      2.75  243900.0 2010-04-29  0.79  0.79  0.79  0.79      0.79      0
1    2010-04-30  11.60  11.61  11.50  11.56     11.56   5400 2019-03-12  2.66  2.78  2.66  2.75      2.75   69200.0 2010-04-30  0.79  0.79  0.79  0.79      0.79      0
2    2010-05-03  11.95  11.95  11.22  11.44     11.44  19400 2019-03-13  2.75  2.80  2.71  2.77      2.77   61200.0 2010-05-03  0.79  0.79  0.79  0.79      0.79      0
3    2010-05-04  11.20  11.49  11.20  11.46     11.46  10700 2019-03-14  2.77  2.79  2.75  2.75      2.75   48800.0 2010-05-04  0.79  0.79  0.66  0.79      0.79   9700
4    2010-05-05  11.50  11.60  11.25  11.50     11.50  13400 2019-03-15  2.76  2.79  2.75  2.79      2.79  124400.0 2010-05-05  0.69  0.80  0.67  0.80      0.80   6700
...         ...    ...    ...    ...    ...       ...    ...        ...   ...   ...   ...   ...       ...       ...        ...   ...   ...   ...   ...       ...    ...
2512 2020-04-22   0.93   1.04   0.93   0.93      0.93   2600        NaT   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN       NaN 2020-04-22  0.72  0.73  0.69  0.73      0.73  14600
2513 2020-04-23   0.94   1.01   0.94   1.01      1.01   2500        NaT   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN       NaN 2020-04-23  0.73  0.77  0.73  0.74      0.74  15200
2514 2020-04-24   1.05   1.05   0.92   1.05      1.05   4400        NaT   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN       NaN 2020-04-24  0.74  0.77  0.74  0.76      0.76   1300
2515 2020-04-27   1.07   1.07   0.92   1.03      1.03   6200        NaT   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN       NaN 2020-04-27  0.77  0.77  0.76  0.76      0.76   3500
2516 2020-04-28   1.07   1.07   0.96   1.00      1.00  22300        NaT   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN       NaN 2020-04-28  0.77  0.77  0.75  0.77      0.77  26100
```

Comment: `pd.concat(list_of_dfs, keys=symbols, axis=1)` then `swaplevel`?

Comment: Gave that a shot:
```
ret =  pd.concat(stock_data.values(), keys=stocks, axis=1)
ret = ret.swaplevel(0, 1)
```
Got:
AttributeError 'Index' object has no attribute 'swaplevel

Comment: You want to pass axis=1 to swaplevel so that it works on columns.

Comment: Getting closers @QuangHoang, threw the output in an edit on the original question.

Comment: now `sort_index(axis=1)` comes to play :-)

Comment: Didn't seem to help. I'm guessing I apply that after the index swap? Either way the index isn't quite right. The index itself needs to be the date with the sub-index being (column, symbol) with the values following after that.

Comment: So I forgot to set_index('Date') before running the concat. That puts the date as the index now which is great, but still not getting quite the right output using concat.

Comment: Hey @QuangHoang, can you post what you wrote in an answer? The end code I ended up implementing looked as follows:

```
        data = pd.concat(stock_data.values(), axis=1,
                          keys=list(stock_data.keys()))
        data.columns = data.columns.swaplevel(0, 1)
        data.sort_index(level=0, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

I derived it from the yfinance implementation:
https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/blob/master/yfinance/multi.py